# No sound output from audio part of component cable on a PS2

Tags: ps2

I have recently got my hands on a fat PS2 (SCPH-30004) meant to be thrown away which I repaired and it works just fine, and it's the only actual PS2 I own right now. Just one thing, I get no audio out from the Analog port. I have it connected to a LED TV via an already owned component cable (YPbPr) which I have successfully tested with 2 or 3 other -slim- PS2s. So, if it's not the TV or the cable it must be the console, right? I can **still** have audio out through the optical out into my Z-5500 speakers, no problem, but not through the red-white stereo cables, while video signal (red-green-blue plugs) is just fine. Could it be a burnt on board circuit fault? How would I go about testing/repairing for the sake of completeness?
Thanks a bunch!

Comment: They prefer the term "big-boned" PS2.

Comment: In all seriousness, do you have another audio component cable to test with? Despite it working with the others, it may be a good idea to test with a separate set of component cables, just for peace of mind.

Comment: Yeah, we don't want to accidentally insult those particular models or their lasers will fail. Instantly. As for the cable, no, I don't have a spare component cable. I do have a composite one though, using which again I get video signal just fine but no sound, which only confirms my suspicions. It's a simple process of elimination really...

Answer (score 1):

There's an option in the PS2 menu that says something like "Audio out" and you can set to Optical or Component (or "Digital audio output " On, Off, I don't remember quite right), you could try that.

If that doesn't work and the video comes fine out of the composite cable and the audio out of the optical, I suggest you just let it go. In my working PS2 the audio that comes out of the component red/white cable is so low and noisy I unplugged it just to be sure I don't accidentally hear it when I switch the tv to "Component".